# html5 canvas code blanking out

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am in desperate need to fix a problem I have in html5 canvas. I am making an educational game, but after adding another photo and making the necessary code changes, but the canvas blanked out. I reverted the changes, but the problem persisted. I spent the past week or so trying to fix it, but I've run out of ideas :( Here is the relevent code (if anyone needs another part, just say so):

```
// Create the canvas
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 1041;
canvas.height = 550;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// Background image
var bgReady = false;
var bgImage = new Image();
bgImage.onload = function () {
bgReady = true;
};
bgImage.src = "images/introbackground.png";
//.... rest of the photos load like this so I won't put it...
// Level 1 background 1 image
var bbg1Ready = false;
var bbg1Image = new Image();
bbg1Image.onload = function () {
    bbg1Ready = false; //Exception since it shouldn't load at the beginning
};
bbg1Image.src = "images/pollutedbeach1.png";

// Game objects
var hero = {
    speed: 200 // movement in pixels per second
};
var level1;
var level2;
var biolevel = false;
//...Code to make the hero picture move with arrow keys and to reset the game are skipped...
if (hero.x <= (level1.x + 345)
&& level1.x <= (hero.x + 32)
&& hero.y <= (level1.y +50)
&& level1.y <= (hero.y + 32)){
    biolevel = true;
    return biolevel;
}

var render = function () {
    if (bgReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
    }
    //...The same for all photos previously loaded...
    if (biolevel == true){
        level1Ready = false;
        level2Ready = false;
        bbg1Ready = true;
        hero.speed = 125;
    }
};
//...Then the main game loop to animate it...
```

Sorry It's kind of long, but I really need a solution. Thanks!

Comment: `return biolevel;` — that isn't inside a function, is it?

Comment: What does your javascript console tell you? Any errors?

Comment: Please post more code, ideally a whole page (like with http://jsfiddle.net ) or post more information about the problem specifically

Comment: @Abody97 it actually is inside a function called update, but most of the function defines the movement of the hero when the user presses the arrow keys, so I didn't put it. I took ur advice and put it on jsfiddle on this link [link](http://jsfiddle.net/XZREX/) I'm still new to jsfiddle so if anyone can't access it, just say so. Thanks again!

Comment: Honestly... I'd recommend starting from scratch. This is a total mess.